# Joomla User & Reporting manager mapping

Tags: joomla, mapping

I want to implement leave management system in joomla. For every leave i want email notification to be sent to employee's manager (reporting manager). I need to do employee - > reporting manager mapping somewhere in database.

Is there any built in utility in joomla user groups which can help me? OR Do I need to simply create mapping table in database?

Please suggest.

Comment: When you say "leave", do you mean the removal of a user account? Is so, how are you removing the account? Manually or through an extension? If through an extension, you can extend it's functionality by creating a plugin

Comment: Thanks for your reply lodder. Leave management system does not mean removing of user. It is a system in which users can apply for leaves (paternity, personal, vacation). Once applied manager gets notification and he/she may approve/reject. It is one of the HR module. Now I need to have mapping between user & manager somewhere (in DB or Joomla backend) so that i can send notification email once any user applies leave in the system. I hope i cleared my requirement.

Comment: Ahh ok that's cleared things up. In which case you should create a plugin extending the functionality of the system. Joomla docs would be a good place to start and read up on it ;)

Answer (score 0):

We are looking for something very similar to run within a Joomla Intranet environment.

I have recently found an extension that might be the kind of thing you are looking for - have a look at **Intranet Attendance Track** by **thagatpam** in the extensions directory.

The extension can track attendance, leave, and has a manager approval system built-in.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It might answer the question.Link only answers are much appreciated here.As the reference link might not exist in future.Here if we see  you might have forgotten to add the link also.